# linux rdp show screen different users

Tags: linux, rdp

I need a software that can run under linux as server and share the current user screen with a remote viewer.

I've tried those software but they start a new session:

> xtighvncviewer
>
> remmina

Tightvncserver on windows works the user screen is shared, on  linux it open a new session for the remote user.

Am I doing something wrong with config?

Are there alternatives?

Comment: Which desktop environment do you use? Each one has a setting to allow remote VNC connections to that user's session.

Comment: I'm using LXDE.

Comment: Solved following:https://forum.lxde.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=31114

Answer (score 0):

- NoMachine is open source and works very well, lot's of options also.
- Gnome allows screen sharing via the "Sharing" settings.
- TeamViewer is commercial software but works very well over the internet.

Comment: NoMachine works as multiuser session, you can re-attach the previously session but cannot attach to the display:0. Other two solution are good answer to the question.